# Can't use aws_cdk.Fn.conditionIf in AutoScalingGroup

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I'm currently making a Stack using python aws cdk V2 and I want to make certain conditions be ran on the template instead in CDK synth so by updating a parameter in cloudformation the template can adapt and not have to be re-synthesised.

Having that said, I currently have this code to make the AutoScaling Group:

```
autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
            self,
            "MagentoAutoScalingInstance",
            auto_scaling_group_name=f"MagentoAutoScalingGroup{self._parameters.environment.value_as_string}",
            vpc=self.vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
            ),
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType(self._parameters.auto_scaling_instance_type.value_as_string),
            instance_monitoring=aws_cdk.Fn.condition_if(
                self._conditions.is_production.logical_id,
                autoscaling.Monitoring.DETAILED,
                autoscaling.Monitoring.BASIC
            ),
            new_instances_protected_from_scale_in=True,
            machine_image=ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(
                generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
            ),
            role=self.auto_scaling_role,
            security_group=self.auto_scaling_sg
        )
```

But when I try `cdk synth` I get the following type error:

```
TypeError: type of argument instance_monitoring must be o
ne of (aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling.Monitoring, NoneType); got jsii._reference_map.InterfaceDynamicProxy instead
```

The option `Fn.condition_if` exists so I suppose this should be possible. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [apply the condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#intrinsic-functions-and-condition-expressions) to a [L1 resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html).

Looking in the CDK [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/5261d742759fcd4aea0d9571e02447b7aad5fcea/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-autoscaling/lib/auto-scaling-group.ts#L1312), we see that the L2 `AutoScalingGroup` construct uses the instance monitoring prop to define a L1 `CfnLaunchConfiguration`.  The L1 construct is given an id of "LaunchConfig".  The Launch Configuration's `instance_monitoring` prop is then set to `True` if the `Monitoring.DETAILED` prop was passed.

So we leave the L2's `instance_monitoring` prop undefined and manually apply the condition to the L1 construct using [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource) syntax:

```py
# Get a reference to the L1 construct
cfn_launch_config = cast(
    autoscaling.CfnLaunchConfiguration, asg.node.find_child("LaunchConfig")
)

# Set the InstanceMonitoring property of the L1 LaunchConfiguration to a Fn::If
cfn_launch_config.instance_monitoring = Fn.condition_if(
    self._conditions.is_production.logical_id, True, False
)
```

The workaround is required because `Fn.condition_if` only resolves at deploy-time.  For this reason, say the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html): *"In general, we recommend against using AWS CloudFormation parameters with the AWS CDK."*